# Vue native - это React native?

Tags: react-native, mobile-development

Планирую начать разработку мобильных приложений на JS-фреймвроке.
Ранее писал на Vue.js. Правильно ли я понимаю, что Vue Native(VN) - это React Native(RN). Только в стиле Vue? Другими словами только обертка.
Стоит ли использовать VN или сразу учится на RN?
Есть ли какие-то нюансы?
Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, [со слов разработчика](https://vue-native.io/docs/#What-is-Vue-Native), Vue Native использует React Native как backend...

> Vue Native is a mobile framework to build truly native mobile app using Vue.js. Its **is designed to connect** React Native and Vue.js.

Для общего развития, стоит. Однако, нужно понимать, что не смотря на то, что RN используется в VN под капотом, вам как прикладному программисту будет дан другой набор компонентов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, компонент [slot](https://vue-native.io/docs/slots.html). Если я не ошибаюсь, множество подобных компонентов будет только расти, так как создан отдельный пакет `vue-native-helper`. Кроме того, нужно понимать, что сама структура .vue файлов кардинально [отличается](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/vue-native-starter-app/blob/master/src/index.vue) наличием тегов `<template>`, `<style>`, `<script>`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вы точно уверены, что хотите начать мобильную разработку на Vue Native при таком различии открытых вакансий?